# Accordion.Toggle Error: React.jsx: type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Good afternoon everyone. I'm using React Bootstrap for styling a modal window and I get an error when I use Accordion.Toggle: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Please find the code for Modal Component attached as well as my dependencies list in package.json. Thanks in advance for your help.

{
"name": "front-end",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.0.2",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-pdf": "^5.4.0",
"react-player": "^2.9.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
},

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, ListGroup, Accordion } from "react-bootstrap";
import CloseModal from "../Assets/Main/CloseModal.png";
import { timersToString } from "../constants/timersToString";

const MarkerModal = ({
  markerModalVisible,
  setMarkerModalVisible,
  sessionDetails,
  sessionID,
  seekToNewMarker,
}) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("");

  const ID = sessionID;
  const sessionIDDetails = sessionDetails.filter(
    ({ sessionID }) => sessionID === ID
  );
  const markerDetails = sessionIDDetails[0]?.Markers;

  const toggleActive = (activeKey) => {
    active === activeKey ? setActive("") : setActive(activeKey);
  };

  console.log(markerDetails);
  return (
    <>
      {sessionID && (
        <Modal
          show={markerModalVisible}
          onHide={() => setMarkerModalVisible(false)}
          backdrop="static"
          keyboard={false}
          centered
          size="lg"
          scrollable={true}
        >
          <Modal.Header
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "rgb(10, 10, 10)",
              border: "2px solid #494949",
              borderBottom: `1px solid #f2bb05`,
            }}
          >
            <Modal.Title style={{ color: "#a7a7a7" }}>
              {`Alert Timestamps`}
            </Modal.Title>
            <img
              src={CloseModal}
              alt="CloseModal"
              onClick={() => {
                setMarkerModalVisible(false);
                setActive("");
              }}
              style={{ width: "4%", opacity: "0.75" }}
            />
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "rgb(10, 10, 10)",
              border: "2px solid #494949",
              borderTop: "none",
              paddingBottom: "25px",
            }}
          >
            <Accordion activeKey={active}>
              {!markerDetails.length && (
                <div style={{ color: "#a7a7a7" }}>
                  {`No alert details to view`}
                </div>
              )}
              {markerDetails.map((marker, idx) => (
                <ListGroup key={marker.mID} variant="flush">
                  <Accordion.Toggle
                    action
                    as={ListGroup.Item}
                    eventKey={marker.mID}
                    onClick={() => toggleActive(marker.mID)}
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: "rgb(10, 10, 10)",
                      color: "#a7a7a7",
                      borderBottom: "1px solid #494949",
                      display: "grid",
                      gridTemplateColumns: "10% 20% 70%",
                    }}
                  >
                    <div>{idx + 1}.</div>
                    <div>{timersToString(marker.timestampSec)}</div>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                        textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                        overflow: "hidden",
                      }}
                    >
                      {marker.msg}
                    </div>
                  </Accordion.Toggle>
                  <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={marker.mID}>
                    <ListGroup.Item
                      style={{
                        textAlign: "justify",
                        textJustify: "inter-word",
                        backgroundColor: "rgb(10, 10, 10)",
                        color: "#a7a7a7",
                        border: "1px solid #494949",
                        borderTop: "none",
                      }}
                    >
                      <b>Message</b> <br />
                      {marker.msg} <br />
                      <div style={{ paddingTop: "7px", textAlign: "right" }}>
                        <Button
                          variant="secondary"
                          onClick={() => {
                            setActive("");
                            //   seekToNewMarker(marker.timestampSec);
                          }}
                          size="sm"
                        >
                          View alert
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                  </Accordion.Collapse>
                </ListGroup>
              ))}
            </Accordion>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      )}
      {!sessionID && <p>Session ID hasn't been provided</p>}
    </>
  );
};

export default MarkerModal;
```